# Why is my DATEPART not working?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to learn SQL and I am having trouble getting DATEPART to work. My table is Payment and the column name is BirthDay.

**Question: What do I have out of order here?**

The question is why is the SQL statement throwing an error. Thanks to the reads they found a simple syntax issue.

What does the @columnName do? Is it better to have the tableName.ColumnName or should a person use the @columnName.

```
     1970-04-05
```

Code:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,p.BirthDay) AS OrderYear,
       DATEPART(mm,  p.BirthDay) AS OrderMonth,
       DATEPART(dd,  p.BirthDay) AS OrderDay
FROM Payment as p;
```

This is the image of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I see a simple syntax error:  remove the comma after `OrderDay`.  Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Those squiggly lines.  They are syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to cast the date as a string. You also have a syntax error with a comma.

```
DECLARE @BirthDay DATETIME
SET @Birthday='04/05/05'

SELECT
    *,
    CAST(OrderYear AS NVARCHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(OrderMonth AS NVARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST(OrderDay AS NVARCHAR(2))
FROM
(
    SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,@BirthDay) AS OrderYear,
           DATEPART(mm,  @BirthDay) AS OrderMonth,
           DATEPART(dd,  @BirthDay) AS OrderDay
)AS X
```

Comment: Would of been helpful to explain why.

Answer (score 6):

You need to lose the comma after orderDay:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,p.BirthDay) AS OrderYear,
   DATEPART(mm,  p.BirthDay) AS OrderMonth,
   DATEPART(dd,  p.BirthDay) AS OrderDay
FROM Payment as p;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments as well as in a similar answer, you may just be running into some syntax errors. Name, the comma after `OrderDay`.

In your screenshot you also have some syntax errors, with the

```
SELECT p.BirthDay
       datepart(dd,p.BirthDay) as Year
from payment as p;
```

Should read something more like this:

```
SELECT p.BirthDay, -- Note the comma!
       DATEPART(dd,p.BirthDay) AS Day --dd = day
FROM Payment as p;
```

As an alternative to using `DATEPART()`, you can use the shortcut functions:

```
SELECT YEAR(p.BirthDay), MONTH(p.BirthDay), DAY(p.BirthDay)
FROM Payment p
```

Comment: I liked all that answers it was difficult to pick which one was the best answer.